# objective c custom class init from array element

Tags: objective-c

I have a person with setter / getter... Now i'm looping an array of that person object. how do i assign the element to a new person.

```
for (int i =0; i<[people count]; i++)
{

   Person *p = [people objectAtIndex:i];
   nsLog(@"%@", [p id]);
}
```

Comment: What is your problem. Your question is not clear. Can you please elaborate more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you're doing it right, except nslog...it should be: `NSLog("%@",p);`

as for a speed thing...use fast enumeration..like this:

```
for(Person *person in people){
//some assign code (Person *p=person);
NSLog("%@",person);
}
```

note that i don't know how `Person` is created...if there is a problem it's there